# parallel payment using paypal newer SDK

Tags: paypal

Am testing my app with paypal lasted SDK for iOS. I see
that newer SDK doesn't support parallel payment ( If am wrong
about this please guide how to implement the parallel payment with latest
latest SDK).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Manoj, Dave from PayPal here.

Yes, you are correct. At this time the PayPal iOS SDK does not support parallel payments.

If you like, you can post an enhancement request over in https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK -- if enough developers agree that this is important for them, that might affect our priorities.

Comment: Hi, I wanna implement parallel payment in my app. I tried rest api on web, but still no success. can u please help me? is there any example coding for this?

Comment: @Manoj that's not an area that I can help you with. You might want to visit https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/support for further discussion of your specific needs.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for your time to reply me.